# Replacing of parentheses in MACROS in c++

Tags: c++, macros

I have defined the following macros:

```
#define START(x) A("start")-
#define ONE(x) -A(#x)
#define END -A("end");
```

and in my simple main i have:

```
(START ONE(one)) ONE(two) END
```

where A("") is a call to constructor of class A. I have made all the operators overload that are necessary, binary and unary minus, yet the compiler outputs that i miss a parenthesis.

What i would like to ask is how exactly the preprocessor replaces my macros into my code because when i run:

```
(A("start") - - A("one")) - A("two") - A("end");
```

it compiles without a problem.

Comment: Just an idea, but if you pass strings to `ONE`, there's no need to use the stringify operator inside.

Comment: I answered your question, but this seems like a really odd thing to do. Are you trying to create a DSL using the preprocessor? I think there are better ways to do that.

Comment: @TartanLlama yes i'm trying to create a DSL but i need to use MACROS. i have made a mistake in the main code using the defines, i just edited my post. thanks for the quick reply though

Answer (score 0):

```
(START ONE("one")) ONE("two") END
```

This will be expanded to this:

```
(START -A("\"one\"")) -A("\"two\"") -A("end");
```

The differences between the real result and your expectation is that `START` is not expanded and `"one"` and `"two"` have their quotes escaped.

To get what you want, `START` should not take arguments and you should not use the stringify operator in `ONE`:

```
#define START A("start")-
#define ONE(x) -A(x)
#define END -A("end");
```

Comment: In general, if a macro is so complicated that you have to ask on stackoverflow.com, then it may be a good idea not to use that macro at all :-)

Comment: @gnasher729 Agreed, hence my comment on the question.